# C# - How Do I Close Main Form Together With Child Forms (while child windows must close ONLY when main form is closing)

Tags: c#, forms, children

I have a main window and a few child windows. Child windows contain some data so I don't want them to be closed. So I hide them while in FormClosing I set `e.Cancel = true;`

But when I want the main window to close (exit application). I have some trouble to exit it. First it wouldn't close. But with an extra variable to note that I'm closing I need 2 clicks to actually close it (problem is before `onFormClosing(mainWIndow, ...)` is executed the framework tries to close the children which will hide themselves first).

```
// main and child windows have this as form closing event proc
private void onFormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender == this) // main
    {
        exitApp = true;
    }
    else
        if (sender == formChild) // child
        {
            if (!exitApp)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                formChild.Hide();
            }
        }
}
```

How can I close them all in 1 click ?

I would also like to avoid `Application.Exit();` because I need to make sure all threads close properly. So best would be a clean close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself:

```
// ...
if (sender == this) // main
{
    exitApp = true;
    FormClosing -= onFormClosing;
    Close();
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force the application with Application.Exit().

Comment: I have periphery that needs to be "shut down" per software because if I don't do it manual action is required and that's not good. I need to avoid `Application.Exit();`. Any other ideas ?

Comment: You should not hide the children.
They will still be instantiated and the main form will have them referenced.
Close them.
And dispose them.